# Write to HTML file from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, netbeans

I know it's been asked before, but I can't seem to figure out any way of doing this. I return a 2D array from a Java method and want to print the results into a table. I have table headers already declared above it. I call createT() after somebody submits a previously defined form. The array the Java method returns is correct, I just can't seem to print off the table.

```
<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
        <script>
            function createT(){
                <% int[][]x = query.getData(); %>
                var result;
                for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
                    results+= "<tr bgcolor = 'red'>";
                    for(var j=0; j<x[i].length; j++){
                        result+="<td>"+x[i][j]+"</td>";
                    }
                    result += "</tr>";
                }
                document.write(result);
            }
        </script>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

[document.write](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp) will delete all existing HTML.

You can try this

```
document.getElementById('YourtableId').appendChild(result);
```

Also create elements using `document.createElement`

Comment: I've tried to use appendChild but still get the same result, which is nothing. I gave tbody an id of "data" and try to append the result at the end. I still have a blank table upon page refresh

Comment: Try to log the result using `console.log(result)` and check in the browser developer's tool the value of it

Comment: Did that, the result variable shows the correct string that should be generated. Is there a way to use a PrintWriter object and just call out.println(whatever)?